# Headless Chrome (Puppeteer) different behaviour running in local docker and remote docker (AWS EC2)

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, cookies, puppeteer, headless

I am trying to debug an issue which causes headless Chrome using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to behave differently on my local environment and on a remote environment such as AWS or Heroku.
The application tries to search public available jobs on LinkedIn without authentication (no need to look at profiles), the url format is something like this: https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=Engineer&location=New+York&redirect=false&position=1&pageNum=0

When I open this url in my local environment I have no problems, but when I try to do the same thing on a remote machine such as AWS EC2 or Heroku Dyno I am redirected to a login form by LinkedIn. To debug this difference I've built a Docker image (based on [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/buildkite/puppeteer)) to have isolation from my local Chrome/profile:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM buildkite/puppeteer

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

CMD node index.js

EXPOSE 9222
```

`index.js`

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
puppeteer.use(require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth")());

const testPuppeteer = async () => {
    console.log('Opening browser');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        slowMo: 20,
        args: [
            '--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0',
            '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
            '--single-process',
            '--lang=en-GB',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            "--proxy-server='direct://",
            '--proxy-bypass-list=*',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--allow-running-insecure-content',
            '--enable-automation',
        ],
    });

    console.log('Opening page...');
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log('Page open');

    const url = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=Engineer&location=New+York&redirect=false&position=1&pageNum=0";
    console.log('Opening url', url);
    await page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
    });
    console.log('Url open');

    // page && await page.close();
    // browser && await browser.close();

    console.log("Done! Leaving page open for remote inspection...");
};

(async () => {
    await testPuppeteer();
})();
```

The docker image used for this test can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/spinlud/puppeteer-linkedin-test).
I've run the image on my local environment with the following command:

```sh
docker run -p 9222:9222 spinlud/puppeteer-linkedin-test
```

Then from the local Chrome browser `chrome://inspect` it should be possible to inspect the GUI of the application (I have deliberately left open the page in headless browser):

[image]

As you can see even in local docker the page opens without authentication.

I've done the same test on an AWS EC2 (Amazon Linux 2) [with Docker installed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html). It needs to be a public instance with SSH access and an inbound rule to allow traffic through port 9222 (for remote Chrome debugging).
I've run the same command:

```sh
docker run -p 9222:9222 spinlud/puppeteer-linkedin-test
```

Then again from local Chrome browser `chrome://inspect`, once added the remote public IP of the EC2, I was able to inspect the GUI of the remote headless Chrome as well:

[image]

As you can see this time LinkedIn requires authentication. We can see also a difference in the cookies:

[image]

I can't understand the reasons behind this different behaviour between my local and remote environment. In theory Docker should provide isolation and in both environment the headless browser should start with no cookies and a fresh (empty session). Still there is difference and I can't figure out why.

Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: Have you figured this out? I think reason is AWS IP-range. In the same way Linkedin is dealing with Tor. To overcome this, you might look into proxy lists. And again, some of them are in Linkedin blacklist.

Comment: Yes it is definetely ip-related. It happens also on Heroku and Travis-CI machines, all hosted on AWS.

Comment: Did a bit off Googling and found that Amazon is sharing their IP range through API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#aws-ip-download). Could be problem for other scraper jobs against sites which don't want scrapers around.